# What to say about time complexity of SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, training, support-vector-machine

I've read it in some literature now that the training speed of SVM (in general) is very low. Why is that the case? What is to say about time complexity of SVM?

Answer (score 1):

The slow training of support vector machines comes from the [Sequential minimal optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_minimal_optimization) algorithm, [which is proven to have](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/282865683_Time_complexity_analysis_of_support_vector_machines_SVM_in_LibSVM) time complexity of roughly $O(n^3)$ (mostly because it involves matrix inversion operations).